# Calling a function from within applicationwillresignactive

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a function `uploadScore()` inside my `UIViewController` Class PlayViewController

When I call this function `uploadScore()` from within `applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)` it throws error Use of unresolved Identifier 'uploadScore'

`uploadScore()` has references to objects in `PlayViewController`.

What am I doing wrong? What would be the best solution?
Code is in swift.

Comment: Show the code you have. Do you have a reference to that view controller in your app delegate?

Comment: that might be the problem. never needed to have a reference to view controller in app delegate. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app delegate doesn't know anything about that view controller, it won't work.

Why not make the view controller itself listen for the notification and do whatever it needs to? The notification name constants are all available in the UIApplication class reference. The methods in the app delegate are convenient, but not magical. Any object can respond to that notification.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need a reference to the viewController in your appDelegate.  Better yet, separate the uploadScore() from your viewController and put it in it's own separate class, then reference that class in your app Delegate, like Uploader.uploadScore().